# How does php output to screen + using mysql to show values on screen?

Tags: php, oop, namespaces, autoload

I'm still relatively new to php.

I created a sub folder below my webroot called lib and added test.php

I then added the following code...

```
<?php
new \Wisdom\Question();
?>
```

I then created another folder within lib called "Wisdom" and a class called "Question" with the following code...

```
<?php

class Question {

function __construct()
{
    $user="username";
    $password="password";
    $database="dbname";
    mysql_connect(localhost,$user,$password);
    @mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM questions";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $num = mysql_numrows($result);
    mysql_close();
    echo "<b><center>Database Output</center></b><br><br>";

    $i=0;

    while($i < $num)
    {
        $description = \mysql_result($result,$i, "description");
        $id = \mysql_result($result,$i, "id");
        echo "<b>$id $description</b>";
        $i++;
    }

}
```

}

When I view the test.php in a browser, it just shows an error 500 (on another note, how do I show php errors on screen?  I tried ERROR_REPORTING(E_ALL) but it didn't do anything.  But it never shows any of the echos during the db connect.  My db has all the fields as expected.  Any ideas?  Thank you!

Comment: For some errors you must use the php configuration from php.ini to display those. Check your php.ini and either enable `display_errors` to display, or `error_log` do log errors to a file. Check your error log then or enable the display of errors. That's because if you do `error_reporting(E_ALL)` inside your code but the loading of the file already does the error, the reporting would not have been enabled.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with: 'new \Wisdom\Question();
'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ha, just found out the php version is 5.2 so won't have namespaces.

Thanks for all the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it's not easy to say what kind of error you are facing. The 500 internal server error can have multiple reasons. It can be something PHP is concerned about, but it can be something with the webserver as well.

So the best answer I can actually give is that you properly configure your [PHP error handling](http://php.net/manual/en/book.errorfunc.php) / [PHP error configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php) and then check the php error log.

In parallel you need to check your webservers error log as well.

Next to that, these are some thoughts I had already because of the code you posted, but this might be misleading:

What you try to achieve needs an autoloader to be enabled. It looks like that the class `\Wisdom\Question` does not exists when you try to instantiate it:

```
new \Wisdom\Question();
```

The autoloader is needed to actually load non-existent classes from the directory/file-layout like you seem to use (I can't specifically say because your question does not give more information).

For the autoloader it looks like you can use any autoloader that is PSR-0 compatible, [for example this one](https://gist.github.com/221634).

Next to that, the class definition needs as well the correct **Namespace** on top:

```
<?php
namespace Wisdom;
class Question {
```

Comment: Hi, what more information would help to give a more specific answer regarding the auto-loader? :)

Comment: I needed to assume that you're not using an autoloader. So first of all it would be good to actually know if you're using an autoloader or not. In case not, I've added a link for an example autoloader you can make use of. It has example code in it's documentation on top of the class.

Comment: Ah, thank you, I've now added that class to my code in the web root, do I have to use it in any specific way?

Comment: You need to include it and then you need to activate the autoloader for your own library path: `$classLoader = new SplClassLoader('Doctrine\Common', '/path/to/doctrine'); $classLoader->register();` - place your own path and namespace therein.

Comment: Ah ok, so for this example would it be $classLoader = new SplClassLoader('Question.php', 'lib/Wisdom/Question.php');   I'm not entirely sure what "Doctrine" is, thanks

Comment: @david99world: I've updated the answer. See the beginning. You first should look by what exactly that 500 internal server error is triggered before you look into the other details.

Answer (score 1):

The `\Wisdom\Question` syntax is for [*namespaces*](http://php.net/namespace), not folders. You need to load the file that contains the class, that cannot be done with that syntax. Use something simple like:

```
require 'Wisdom/Question.php';
new Question;
```

Comment: ah, I tried this and it still just showed an error 500 on chrome :( thanks for the help though, do you have any other ideas?